# Animation within ng-repeat - not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm using angularJS (1.3.0-rc.4) and I'm trying to implement a fade-out animation within ng-repeat elements (or at this point any animation when an item is being added).

**template file:**

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages"
    class="msg-popup alert alert-{{ message.type }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    <span class="msg-content">{{ message.content }}</span>
</div>
```

**scss file:**

```
.msg-popup {
    &.ng-enter {
        -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
        -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
        -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
        transition:0.5s linear all;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

I guess at this point when any new element is being added to the list it should fade out in 0.5s? But it doesn't.

If helpfull - that is how the list is being loaded - messenger is a service that holds the data and getMessages(5) retrieves 5 latest messages:

**module controller:**

```
$scope.$on('messenger::updated', function(event, message) {
    $scope.messages = messenger.getMessages(5);
});
```

**EDIT:**
One more question related with it, should I attach to bower "nganimate" as well ?

Comment: You have to specify CSS value for calass without ng-enter. Add `opacity:1` just before `&.ng-enter {`

Comment: Still nothing, is it obligatory to download ngAnimation package with angularJS 1.3.0-rc.4 or is it already embedded ?

Comment: Here is what you have to have at the end in your CSS. https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/blob/master/toaster.css#L192-231.